# Highlight row of JSF datatable

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2

I want to highlight row into JSF table when the mouse pointer is on the row. I found this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-highlight-table-row-record-on-hover-with-jquery/).

I tried to implement the example here:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $("tr").not(':first').hover(
              function () {
                $(this).css("background","yellow");
              }, 
              function () {
                $(this).css("background","");
              }
            );

        </script>

        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="NVIDIA.com" /> History Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>

        </div>  

        <div id="greenBand" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-allh" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Dashboard"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_sessions.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMap" style="width:750px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

                    <h:form id="form">

                        <!-- The sortable data table -->
                        <h:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{SessionsController.dataList}" var="item">


                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Account Session ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Account Session ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.aSessionID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="User ID" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="User ID" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.userID}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity Start Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity Start Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityStart}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity End Time" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity End Time" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activityEnd}" />
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:commandLink value="Activity" actionListener="#{SessionsController.sort}">
                                        <f:attribute name="sortField" value="Activity" />
                                    </h:commandLink>
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{item.activity}" />
                            </h:column>
                        </h:dataTable>

                        <!-- The paging buttons -->
                        <h:commandButton value="first" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" />
                        <h:commandButton value="prev" action="#{SessionsController.pagePrevious}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow == 0}" />
                        <h:commandButton value="next" action="#{SessionsController.pageNext}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" />
                        <h:commandButton value="last" action="#{SessionsController.pageLast}"
                                         disabled="#{SessionsController.firstRow + SessionsController.rowsPerPage >= SessionsController.totalRows}" />
                        <h:outputText value="Page #{SessionsController.currentPage} / #{SessionsController.totalPages}" />
                        <br />

                        <!-- The paging links -->
                        <ui:repeat value="#{SessionsController.pages}" var="page">
                            <h:commandLink value="#{page}" actionListener="#{SessionsController.page}"
                                           rendered="#{page != SessionsController.currentPage}" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{page}" escape="false"
                                          rendered="#{page == SessionsController.currentPage}" />
                        </ui:repeat>
                        <br />

                        <!-- Set rows per page -->
                        <h:outputLabel for="rowsPerPage" value="Rows per page" />
                        <h:inputText id="rowsPerPage" value="#{SessionsController.rowsPerPage}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                        <h:commandButton value="Set" action="#{SessionsController.pageFirst}" />
                        <h:message for="rowsPerPage" errorStyle="color: red;" />

                    </h:form>

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdiva" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:400px">

                </div>   

                <div id="settingsdivb" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:800px">

                </div>   
            </div>  
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

Nothing happens. I suppose that the JavaScript must be able to work. Is there a diffidence in highlighting row in a JSF table and a normal HTML table? Maybe the problem is the version of JQuery?

Best wishes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that your script gets executed *before* the DOM is completely loaded.

You can either put your script as it is at the bottom of the page or call it when the document is ready by putting it inside  `$(function() {})`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("tr").not(':first').hover(
      function () {
        $(this).css("background","yellow");
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).css("background","");
      }
    );
  })
</script>
```

Comment: How can we add the same thing on click event of the tr?

Answer (score 1):

You can use these js action call in dataTable:

```
onrowmouseover="this.style.cursor='default';this.style.backgroundColor='#F1F1F1';" 
onrowmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#{a4jSkin.tableBackgroundColor}'"
```

Comment: What is the proper way to add this js action? Where I have to place this code?

Comment: you can use it in datatable tag like this:

<h:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{SessionsController.dataList}" var="item" onrowmouseover="this.style.cursor='default';this.style.backgroundColor='#F1F1F1';" 
onrowmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#{a4jSkin.tableBackgroundColor}'">
.......
</h:dataTable>

Comment: Yes I try it but Netbeans returns me error: The attribute onrowmouseover is not defined in the component's interface

Comment: check it with onmouseover and onmouseout instead of onrowmouseover and onmouseout.