# Richfaces Javascript not firing

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, richfaces

I'm trying highlight the currently selected row of a table rendered using Ricfaces, but it's not working. Here's my code:

facelet:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" template="templates/main.xhtml">

<ui:define name="body">
    <h:form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['result.legend']}" />
            </legend>

            <rich:dataTable id="resultTable" onRowMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#f1f1f1'" 
                onRowMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor=''"
                value="#{searchController.result}" var="row">
                <c:forEach items="${searchController.headers}" var="headr"
                    varStatus="status">
                    <rich:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{headr}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{row[status.count-1]}" />
                    </rich:column>
                </c:forEach>
            </rich:dataTable>

        </fieldset>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

I'm having trouble pasting the whole template (main.xhtml) source code. This is the content of the h : body tag (just discovered why :-) ):

```
<rich:panel styleClass="mainPanel">
    <ui:include src="../common/header.xhtml"></ui:include>
    <ui:insert name="body"></ui:insert>
</rich:panel>
```

pom dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--dependency> <groupId>javax.faces</groupId> <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId> 
        </dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Where searchController.headers is a List< String > and searchController.result is a List< List< String > >. The table itself is rendered correctly.

What am I missing here?

I'm using Richfaces 4.2.2.Final, developing on Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/10129551/1065197

Comment: I'm trying to implement onRowMouseOver as suggested in that thread. I'm basing my attempt on an example I found here: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf, but what I've done doesn't work. I don't believe this is a duplicate.

Comment: You're getting the concepts wrong.The onRowMouseOver and onRowMouseOut are using `this` so you're changing the `rich:dataTable` background color. See the link what I've posted, because to achieve what you need you should use JavaScript like BalusC shows in this [Highlight rows on click](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#HighlightRowsOnClick) sample, or jQuery as the link I've provided as duplicate.

Comment: Can you explain why the example I posted works, without using custom Javascript and my attempt doesn't? I'd like to use the same approach, if possible. As you've probably guessed, I'm new to Richfaces :-).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this question is not a duplicate as richfaces handles this a bit different than plain jsf.

I created two js functions in my application for that task:

```
function mouseOutRichRow(row) {
    if (row.highlight != true) {
        row.style.backgroundColor=row.oldColor;
    }
}
function mouseOverRichRow(row) {
    if (row.highlight != true) {
        row.oldColor=row.style.backgroundColor;
        row.style.backgroundColor='#FFFF8A';
    }
}
```

They are bound to the onRowMouse-events:

```
<rich:dataTable
    onRowMouseOver="mouseOverRichRow(this);"
    onRowMouseOut="mouseOutRichRow(this);"
    ....>
```

In fact, Luiggi Mendoza's comment is wrong - Richfaces applies those parameters to each row, so `this` has the correct scope.

**Edit:**
If this still doesn't work, try not to use `c:forEach`. This is the old jsp-way and does not work well with the jsf-lifecycle. Use `ui:repeat` or `a4j:repeat` instead.

Comment: The link posted by @JazzHands points to RF 3.3 Here is the link with RF 4.x [DataTable Style](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataTable&sample=tableStyling&skin=blueSky), and they use jQuery scripts to add the events. Also, I've tried your example and doesn't work using RF 4.2 and GlassFish 3.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. My (and JazzHand's) example is for RF 3.3. I overread him mentioning RF 4.

Comment: @Roben - I'm using c:forEach, as rich:columns isn't implemented in v4.2

Comment: I've changed the events to `onrowmouseover` and `onrowmouseout` (both in lower case) and it worked.

Comment: Still, `c:forEach` seems very wrong to me. Does RF 4 not supply a var/value property for `rich:dataTable`?

Comment: @Luiggi - it works! Maybe they made it case-sensetive in v4.2... I can't think why the example I found works otherwise...

Comment: @Roben - RF 4 does have a var property - it's in my code. I've had to use c:forEach in order to render a table with dynamic columns as well as rows.

Comment: Thank you both for your contributions. PS, how come this thread has a score of -2?

Comment: @JazzHands - Oh, now I see it. Nevermind ;) (definitely to hot today)

Comment: @JazzHands XHTML is more sensitive than JSP. It looks like you're new to JSF 2 and Facelets, but don't worry you will learn while coding :).